# If $G$ is abelian and $\vert G\vert = p^n \implies G \cong \mathbb{Z}/{p^{n_1}\mathbb{Z}} \times \cdots\times \mathbb{Z}/{p^{n_k}\mathbb{Z}} $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Context: General work on abelian group.

**Statement**:

> Let $G$ be an abelian group of order $p^n$, where $p$ is prime and $n$ is a strictly positive integer. Then there exist a positive integer $k>0$, strictly positive integers $n_1,...,n_k$, such that $$G \cong \mathbb{Z}/{p^{n_1}\mathbb{Z}} \times \cdots\times \mathbb{Z}/{p^{n_k}\mathbb{Z}} $$

**Proof:** We proceed by recurrence on  $n>0$.

$n=1$: no problem, can be shown easily that the statement is true

Then, we suppose there exists an integer $l$ such that for every $0<l\leq n$, the statement is true.

Case 1: If $G$ is cyclic, it's easy; I don't have problems.

Case 2: If $G$ is not cyclic: Let's consider $x\in G$ of maximal order. Then $\langle x\rangle$ has same order.

As $G$ is a finite group and $\vert G/\langle x\rangle \vert < p^{n+1}$, we have by hypothesis that there exists $({x_1,...,x_k})$ such that :
$$G/\langle x\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^{x_1}\mathbb{Z} \times \cdots\times \mathbb{Z}/p^{x_k}\mathbb{Z}  $$

**Lemma (that I admit)**: if $x$ is a maximal order element of an abelian finite group $G$, then for each $\overline{y}\in G/\langle x\rangle$, there exist $y\in \overline y $ such that the order of $y$ is the same as the order of $\overline{y}$.

It seems I need to use this lemma to finish.

Also, if the question has already been asked and I missed it in my searches, I'd be thankful to have a link to it.

Comment: Are you French?  In English, positive means $x > 0$, not $x \geq 0$ (certainly in algebra).  So people don't write "strictly positive".

Comment: A good lemma to use is that for a finite abelian $p$-group $G$, each $g \in G$ of maximal order leads to a direct product decomposition $G = \langle g\rangle \times H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$.

Comment: For a proof see [wikipedia](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups).